# Filter keys in Object

Tags: node.js, filtering

I am trying to implement a simple extraction function that connects to the Poloniex.returnTicker endpoint and, extract the 'last' key for any currency pairs starting with 'BTC'. There are a number of keys starting with 'BTC' but, my extraction function is stopping after returning exactly one key. I am mapping the extracted data in an object in the following manner:

```
extracted = {
    BTC: {
        STR: {
            lastPrice: price
         },
         ETH: {
            lastPrice: price
         }, //...
   }, //...
}
```

I wrote the following function for extraction:

```
module.exports = {
extractData: (tickerdata, marker) => {
    if(!!!marker){
        marker = 'BTC';
    }
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        let currentBuffer = {};
        Object.keys(tickerdata)
            .filter((key) => {
                return key.startsWith(marker);
            })
            .forEach((filtKey) => {
                let c = filtKey.split('_'),
                    src = c[0],
                    dst = c[1];
                currentBuffer[src] = {};
                Object.keys(tickerdata[filtKey])
                    .forEach((entry) => {
                        if(!!!(dst in currentBuffer[src])){
                            currentBuffer[src][dst] = {};
                        }
                        if(entry == 'last'){
                            currentBuffer[src][dst]['lastPrice'] = tickerdata[filtKey][entry];
                        }

                    });
            });
            res(currentBuffer);
    });
},//... rest of the module exports
```

For reference, each call to return ticker endpoint returns data in the following format: [Poloniex API](https://poloniex.com/support/api/). Look at returnTicker endpoint for example.

I am guessing that there is a logical error in the extraction function but, I am not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

What about this code?

```
module.exports = {
    extractData: (tickerdata, marker) => 
        Object.keys(tickerdata)
            .map(x => x.split('_'))
            .filter(x => x && x[0] == (marker || 'BTC') && x[1])
            .map(x => x[0] + '_' + x[1])
            .map(x => [x, Object.keys(tickerdata[x])
                .map(y => [y, tickerdata[x][y].lastPrice])]);
```

and usage:

```
const extracted = {
    ETH_STR: {
        BTC: {
            lastPrice: 1
        }
    },
    BTC_ETH: {
        STR: {
            lastPrice: 1
        }
    },
    BTC_STR: {
        STR: {
            lastPrice: 1
        },
        ETH: {
            lastPrice: 2
        }, //...
    }, //...
};

const result = extractData(extracted, 'BTC');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

with result

```
[["BTC_ETH",[["STR",1]]],["BTC_STR",[["STR",1],["ETH",2]]]]
```

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that the `tickerdata[marker]` will result into `undefined`. There are no such fields in the tickerdata object. Each key is a pair of currencies where, the keys are in the format BTC_STR, USDT_STR, etc. The extract function should first separate the currency pairs and, identify the base currencies (BTC, USDT). For each base currencies, it maps the info of the destination currency (in case of the example, STR). And for clarification, the `extracted` object is an object I want to use for storing the extracted data.

Answer (score 0):

I have tinkered around with my code and, finally was able to make it work. Besides adding more code for extracting data from the API response object, `tickerdata`, I have changed the promise to `return` instead of `resolve`. This ensured that the flow remains in proper sequence. I used a `then` clause on the `promise` to retrieve the `extracted` values (named `buff`). Here is the full working code:

```
`module.exports = {
extractData: (markers) => {
    // extracts the data for all markers which, are a comma separated string of base currencies
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        markers = (!!!(markers) ? 'USDT,BTC' : markers)
        polinst.returnTicker()
            .then((tickerdata) => {
                let buff = {};
                markers.split(',').forEach((marker) => {
                    Object.keys(tickerdata)
                    .filter((key) => {
                        return key.startsWith(marker);
                    })
                    .forEach((fkey) => {
                        let c = fkey.split('_'),
                            src = c[0],
                            dst = c[1];
                        buff[src] = (!!!(buff[src]) ? {} : buff[src]);
                        buff[src][dst] = (!!!(buff[src][dst]) ? {} : buff[src][dst]);
                        Object.keys(tickerdata[fkey])
                            .forEach((k) => {
                                if(k == 'last'){
                                    buff[src][dst]['lastPrice'] = tickerdata[fkey][k];
                                }
                                else if(k == 'quoteVolume'){
                                    buff[src][dst]['volume'] = tickerdata[fkey][k];
                                }
                                else if(k == 'lowestAsk'){
                                    buff[src][dst]['ask'] = tickerdata[fkey][k];
                                }
                                else if(k == 'highestBid'){
                                    buff[src][dst]['highestBid'] = tickerdata[fkey][k];
                                }
                            });
                    });
                });
                return buff;
            }).then((d)=>{
                res(d);
            }).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err);
            });
    });    
},

};`
```